# In Next.js SSR page in the app directory, how to redirect to the "not found" page?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, next.js, server-side-rendering

I'm migrating a Next.js application from using the `pages/` folder to using the `app/` folder. I follow the [Migrate page to app guide](https://nextjs.org/docs/app/building-your-application/upgrading/app-router-migration#migrating-from-pages-to-app).

In my `pages/index.ts`, I have `getServerSideProps` like so:

```
interface ThingPageProps {
  thing: string;
}
interface Params extends ParsedUrlQuery {
  id: string;
}

export const getServerSideProps: GetServerSideProps<ThingPageProps, Params> = async context => {
  const { id } = context.params!;
  try {
    const thing = await findThingById(id);
    if (thing) {
      return { props: { thing } };
    } else {
      return { notFound: true };
    }
  } catch (e) {
    return { notFound: true };
  }
}

const MyThingPage: NextPage<ThingPageProps> = ({ thing }: ThingPageProps) => (
  <h1>{ thing }</h1>
)

export default MyThingPage;
```

Now how do I translate that to `app/page.ts` where I don't have the `getServerSideProps` with an option to return `{ notFound: true }`?

This is how far I am:

```js
export default async function MyThingPage({ params }) {      // params is implicitly any type
  const thing = await findThingById(params.id);
  return (
    <h1>{ thing }</h1>
  );
}
```

Comment: Yes, this is perfect.

Comment: Glad it did! I would leave your question, I mean, not delete it. Some people would search on google the way you asked, and they will get help with the linked thread.

Comment: @YoussoufOumar I appreciate your efforts! Thank you!